# Example of colimit of Hausdorff spaces which is not Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

In https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195248/co-hausdorffification, it is mentioned that the subcategory of **Top** consisting of Hausdorff spaces is not closed under colimits.

The simplest colimit I could think of is the disjoint union, but this doesn't appear to provide a counterexample.

*What is an example of a colimit of Hausdorff spaces which is non-Hausdorff?*

Comment: Isn't the quotient space construction a colimit?  A quotient of Hausdorff spaces need not be Hausdorff, so that might provide your example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the pushout 
$$\begin{matrix}
[0,1) &\to & [0,1] \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
[0,1] &\to & X
\end{matrix}$$
where all maps are inclusions. Here $X$ (an interval "with two $1$'s") is not Hausdorff.

**Edit:** I realized that *a diagram without a colimit in $\mathbf{Haus}$* is different from *a diagram whose colimit is not Hausdorff*. In that MO question you mention, someone commented that Hausdorff spaces are not closed under taking colimits. The above diagram is an example where the colimit in $\mathbf{Top}$ is not Hausdorff, so it is not the colimit in $\mathbf{Haus}$. But that does not mean that this diagram of Hausdorff spaces does not have a colimit in $\mathbf{Haus}$, it is just not the usual colimit. In fact, every diagram in $\mathbf{Haus}$ has a colimit in $\mathbf{Haus}$, and it is obtained by applying the [*largest Hausdorff quotient functor*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471238/construction-of-a-hausdorff-space-from-a-topological-space/471274?s=4|0.0000#471274) $h:\mathbf{Top}\to\mathbf{Haus}$ to the colimit in $\mathbf{Top}$. This is because the functor $h$ preserves colimits, being left adjoint to the inclusion $i:\mathbf{Haus}\to\mathbf{Top}$. So the category $\mathbf{Haus}$ **is** closed  under colimits.

So if the functor $i$ preserves a colimit, then the colimit in $\mathbf{Top}$ is a Hausdorff space. Conversely, if the colimit is Hausdorff, then applying $h$ (which on Hausdorff spaces is the identity) gives just this space as the colimit in $\mathbf{Haus}$, so the inclusion $i$ preserves the colimit.

For the diagram above, the colimit in $\mathbf{Haus}$ is the space $[0,1]$ since in the Hausdorff quotient $h(X)$ both $1$'s are identified.

Answer (score 4):

Quotient spaces of Hausdorff spaces may (sadly) not be Hausdorff themselves. So consider a Hausdorff space $X$ and an equivalence relation $\mathcal R\subset X\times X$ on $X$ such that the quotient is non Hausdorff. The quotient space $X/\mathcal R$ is the coequalizer of the two projections $\mathcal R\xrightarrow{\pi_1,\pi_2} X$:
$$\mathrm{Coeq}\left(\mathcal R\,\underset{{\pi_2}}{\overset{\pi_1}{\rightrightarrows}}X\right)=X/\mathcal R$$
where $\mathcal R$ is given the subspace topology from $X\times X$, which is Hausdorff. This gives an example of a colimit of Hausdorff spaces that isn't Hausdorff.