# Identifying points in a topological space when they are not Hausdorff separated (reference request)

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to trace a construction.

The category $Haus$ of Hausdorff topological spaces and continuous functions between them naturally embeds into the category $Top$ of all topological spaces.

This embedding has a left adjoint $L:Top\to Haus$ obtained by a repeated quotient by the transitive closure of the negation of Hausdorff-separation (i.e. every open neighbourhood of $p$ intersects every open neighbourhood of $p'$).

Can anyone recommend a good reference or references for this construction?

Thank you.

Comment: The "simple" quotient you describe doesn't work--that quotient may not be Hausdorff (I give an example of this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763908/making-a-topological-space-hausdorff)).  To get a Hausdorff space you have to iterate it transfinitely.  Some similar questions that have been asked before: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78175/largest-hausdorff-quotient, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471238/construction-of-a-hausdorff-space-from-a-topological-space

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for the pointers.