# Subcategories of T1, Hausdorff and TD spaces are reflective subcategories of Category *Top*.

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, separation-axioms

How do I construct a T1, Hausdorff and TD reflections  to show that subcategories of T1, Hausdorff and TD spaces are reflective subcategories of Category Top?

The T0 reflection is just the T0 quotient of a space X. What about the others?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/471238/4280) talk in detail about the Hausdorff reflection.

The $T_1$ reflection of $X$ is the quotient under the intersection of all equivalence relations on $X$ that have closed equivalence classes, see [the post here with an attempted proof](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2004&task=show_msg&msg=1220.0003.0001.0001.0001) (the previous one has the statement).

My details: Let $X$ be any space and define $$\mathcal{C} = \{S \subseteq X \times X: S \text{ is an equivalence relation and } \forall x \in X: [x]_S \text{ closed in } X\}$$ where $[x]_S$ is the class of $x \in X$ under $S$.
This is a non-empty set of equivalence relations as the trivial relation $R= X \times X$ is in $\mathcal{C}$. As the intersection of any family of equivalence relations is again an equivalence relation $R= \bigcap\{S \in \mathcal{C}\}$ is well- defined. As for any $x$ we have $$[x]_R = \bigcap \{[x]_S: S \in \mathcal{C}\}$$ and intersections of closed sets are closed, we have that $R$ also has the property that all classes are closed and so $X/R$ is a well-defined $T_1$ space in the quotient topology (with quotient map $q: X \to X/R$ defined as usual by $q(x)= [x]_R$). This $(X/R,q)$ is the $T_1$-reflection of $X$: let $Y$ be any $T_1$ space and $f: X \to Y$ continuous. Then $R_f = \{(x,x') \in X \times X: f(x)=f(x')\}$ is an equivalence relation and as $[x]_{R_f} = f^{-1}[\{f(x)\}]$, $R_f \in \mathcal{C}$, and so $R \subseteq R_f$, which implies that if $[x]_R =[x']_R$ we have that $f(x) = f(x')$ too, so that $\tilde{f}([x]_R) = f(x)$ is well-defined and continuous as $q^{-1}[\tilde{f}^{-1}[O]] = f^{-1}[O]$ for all $O$ and $X/R$ has the quotient topology w.r.t. $q$. It's clear that $\tilde{f}$ is unique.

That [same linked thread](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2004&task=show_msg&msg=1220.0003.0001.0001.0001.0001) claims that $T_D$ is not reflective because $S_2^{\aleph_0}$, where $S_2$ is the Sierpiński two-space, is not $T_D$. More is explained in the introduction of [this paper](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2004/253461.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will add this on my thesis. I will assume it's original

Comment: @Percy the $T_1$ reflexion is not original of course. It’s a standard result.

Comment: Hi @Henno. Been trying to get some understanding of the T1 reflection. For the T0 reflection, we compare equivalence classes by using closures. How do we describe equivalence classes for the T1 reflection? I have noticed the [x]_{R} that you gave, but how do I compare [x]_{R} and [y]_{R}?

Comment: @Percy The construction is valid but not very direct: you have to first know all equivalence relations on the space with closed classes. So $x$ and $y$ are equivalent exactly when they are in the same class for all such equivalence relations. It refines the relation used in th e$T_0$ reflection, because if $y \in \overline{\{x\}}$ we certainly will have that $x$ and $y$ are in the same class for $R$ too. The reverse need not hold, of course. The $T_0$-reflection relation has all classes closed so it's one of the relations we intersect in the definition of the $T_1$ reflection.

Answer (score 0):

@Henno .
This is what I tried for the T1 Reflection. But I hardly used the fact that singleton sets of a T1 space are closed. Any suggestion?

Let $R$ be the smallest equivalence relation $S$ on $X$ such that $X/S$ is closed. Denote by $X/ R$ the quotient space and $p$ the quotient map from $X$ onto $X/ R$. We show that $X /R$ is the $T_{1}$ reflection of $X$. That $X/R$ is $T_{1}$ follows from the fact that a quotient space is $T_{1}$ if and only if each equivalence class of $X$ is closed, [41]. Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a continuous map from $X$ to a $T_{1}$ space $Y$. Define a function $g:X/R\longrightarrow Y$ by $[x]\mapsto f(x)$. Observe that $g$ is defined since for any $[x], [y]\in X/R$, if $g([x])\neq g([y])$, then $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Now, $\{f(x)\}$ and $\{f(y)\}$ are disjoint closed subsets of $Y$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ are disjoint closed sets of $X$. Because $[x]\subseteq f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})$ and $[y]\subseteq f^{-1}(\{f(y)\})$, it follows that $[x]\neq [y]$.\
         For continuity of $g$, let $U$ be a closed subset of $Y$. Then $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed in $X$. Observe that 
         \begin{align*}
    g^{-1}(U)&=\{[x]:f(x)\in U\}\\
    &=\{[x]:x\in f^{-1}(U)\}\\
    &=p(f^{-1}(U))
   \end{align*}
        Now, 
        \begin{align*}
   p^{-1}(p(f^{-1}(U)))&=\{x: f(x)\in p(f^{-1}(U))\}\\
   &=\{x:x\in f^{-1}(U)\}\\
   &=f^{-1}(U)\subseteq f^{-1}(U)\subseteq p^{-1}(p(f^{-1}(U)))
  \end{align*}
        Therefore, $p^{-1}(p(f^{-1}(U)))=f^{-1}(U)$. By definition of a quotient map $p$, $g^{-1}(U)$ is closed in $X/R$. Thus $g$ is continuous.\
        Clearly $g$ is unique.\
        So, the $T_{1}$ quotient space $X/R$ is the $T_{1}$ reflection of $X$.

Comment: What does $X/S$ is closed mean? Why would a smallest one exist?

Comment: Yes, but a set is always closed in itself. So $X/S$ is closed means nothing.

Comment: There is a least one such equivalence relation.

Comment: You need more of an argument that $g$ is well-defined. You need that $R_f $ is contained in $R$.

Comment: $R_f$ is the equivalence relation induced by $f$, points are equivalent iff they have the same value. This has closed classes if $Y$ is $T_1$...

Comment: I have added my own much simpler proof to my posting.